# Remove all labels from mplfinance

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to remove all the labels from an mplfinance plot.

Using empty spaces on y axis still leaves the scaling label and I can't seem to reove the x labeling at all.

Appreciate if anyone knew how to do this.

Trying to achieve:

[image: Trying to achieve]

Current:

[image: Current]

code:

```
import mplfinance as mpf

mpf.plot(data[i-50:i], type='candle',volume=True, mav=(7,12), style='yahoo', figratio = (3.12,3.12))
```

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of mplfinance (0.12.5a3) has a new kwarg `axisoff=True` will remove all labels and axis lines.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is the code.

You can try:

```
plt.set_xlabel("")
```

or could you please provide an example, that will be really helpful.

Thanks